# How to set the cursor in a custom NSView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, nscursor

I have a custom view which needs to set a cursor depending on where the mouse is. I use `[NSCursor set]` to set the cursor in a `mouseMoved:` handler. This works on OS X 10.5, but most of the time not on 10.6. Sometimes the cursor changes, but it usually doesn't.

The problem is I have to set the cursor in response to a `mouseMoved:` event, I can't register cursor rects or use a `NSTrackingArea` and the `updateCursor:` event. I am working on a Cocoa frontend for the NetSurf browser. The engine expects mouse movement events from the frontend. If the cursor is over a link or something that requires a different cursor the engine calls a function from the frontend to set the new cursor.

Any ideas of how to make this work on Snow Leopard?

Comment: Do you see any cursor flicker? Does it look like the cursor is changing briefly? Can you develop a sample application which demonstrates the problem? (I can use [NSCursor set] successfully on 10.6) There are other functions which can be called to change the cursor (the deprecated SetCursor for example), are any of them being used? I might suggest watching all calls to [NSCursor set] - see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html

Comment: How does (positionally) your current code know when and to what cursor to change to?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should use CursorRects to avoid other views changing your cursor. But since you can't do that, you can prevent their interference by disabling CursorRects at the window level, on mouse entering your view. On mouse exiting your view, enable back cursorrects for the window.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use NSCursor object with push and pop in mouseEnter and mouseExit